# Did old DOS C compilers implement double as 32-bit?

Tags: c, graphics, 3d, floating-point, dos

I'm reading Michael Abrash's Graphics Programming Black Book which is all about 3D graphics performance, so I was surprised to find that a lot of the C code there uses `double` instead of `float`. We're talking about early 90s computers (286, 386, Pentium) and MS-DOS C compilers, so what's the reason for using `double` in that era? Didn't `float` exist or was `double`'s and `float`'s precision different than today?

In short, why `double` was used in performance-critical code in that era?

Comment: Read up on the x87 math coprocessor and how floating point worked on x86 before SSE was introduced.

Comment: As for why double instead of float... Same reason as preferring it today... Higher precision, bigger range of values. Plus the peculiarities of x87.

Comment: What did your research for the documentation of the compiler in question reveal?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the issue at that time was that the FPU was set to do calculations in double precision, so if you actually used floats, then you had to pay an extra cost for conversion.  In many cases using doubles was a performance win even though they took 64 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there was no C compiler targeting MS-DOS that used a 32-bit wide `double`, instead they all used a 64-bit wide `double`.  This was certainly the case by the early 90's. Based on quick read of the "Floating Point for Real-Time 3D" chapter of the book, it appears the Michael Abrash thought that floating-point math of any precision was too slow on anything less than a Pentium CPU.  Either the floating-point code you're looking was intended for Pentium CPUs or it was used on a non-critical path where performance doesn't matter.  For performance critical code meant for earlier CPUs, Abrash implies that he would've used fixed-point arithmetic instead.

In a lot of cases using `float` instead of `double` wouldn't have actually made much difference. There's a few reasons.  First, if you don't have an [x87 FPU (floating-point unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87) installed (a separate chip before the '486), using less precision wouldn't improve performance enough to make software emulated floating-point arithmetic fast enough to be useful for game.  The second is that the performance of most x87 FPU operations wasn't actually affected by precision.  On a Pentium CPU only division was faster if performed at a narrower precision. For earlier x87 FPUs I'm not sure precision affected division, though it could affect the performance of multiplication on the 80387. On all x87 FPUs addition would've been the same speed regardless of precision.

The third is that the specific C data type used, whether a 32-bit `float`, the 64-bit `double`, or even the 80-bit `long double` that many compilers supported, didn't actually affect the precision the FPU used during calculations.  This is because the FPU didn't have different instructions (or encodings) for the three different precisions it supported. There was no way to tell it perform a `float` addition or a `double` divide.  Instead it performed all arithmetic at a given precision that was set in the FPU's control register. (Or more accurately stated, it performed arithmetic as if using infinite precision and then rounding the result to the set precision.) While it would've been possible to change this register every time a floating-point instruction is used, this would cause massive decrease in performance, so compilers never did this.  Instead they just set it to either 80-bit or 64-bit precision at program startup and left it that way.

Now it was actually a common technique for 3D games to set the FPU to single-precision.  This meant floating-point arithmetic, whether using `double` or `float` types, would be performed using single-precision arithmetic. While this would end up only affecting the performance of floating-point divides, 3D graphics programming tends to do a lot divisions in critical code (eg. perspective divides), so this could have a significant performance improvement.

There is however one way that using `float` instead of `double` could improve performance, and that's simply because a `float` takes up half the space of a `double`.  If you have a lot of floating-point values then having to read and write half as much memory can make a significant difference in performance.  However, on Pentium or earlier PCs this wouldn't result in the huge performance difference it would today.  The gap between CPU speed and RAM speed wasn't as wide back then, and floating-point performance was a fair bit slower. Still, it would be a worth while optimization if the extra precision isn't needed, as is usually the case in games.

Note that modern x86 C compilers don't normally use x87 FPU instructions for floating-point arithmetic, instead they use scalar SSE instructions, which unlike the x87 instructions, do come in single- and double-precision versions. (But no 80-bit wide extended-precision versions.)  Except for division, this doesn't make any performance difference, but does mean that results are always truncated to `float` or `double` precision after every operation.  When doing math on the x87 FPU this truncation would only happen when the result was written to memory.  This means SSE floating-point code has now has predictable results, while x87 FPU code had unpredictable results because it was in general hard to predict when the compiler would need to spill a floating-point register into memory to make room for something else.

So basically using `float` instead of `double` wouldn't have made a big performance difference except when storing floating-point values in a big array or other large data structure in memory.